# Rellenar circulo SVG en función de un radio button

Tags: html, css, svg

Tengo una especie de semáforo y quisiera rellenarlo en función de la opción que vaya escogiendo el usuario con un **radio button** con valores **{0,1,2,3}**. Con 0, se apagan todos, con 1 se enciende el primero, con 2 se enciende el primero y el segundo y con 3 se encienden todos.

He metido cada círculo en una división simplemente para alinearlo a mi manera con el css correspondiente.

```
<div class="TLightR">
<svg id="svg1" style="width: 1.5in; height: 0.55in">
<circle id="circle1" r="20" cx="30" cy="30" style="fill: red; stroke: black;      stroke-width: 2"/>
</svg>
</div>

<div class="TLightY">
<svg id="svg2" style="width: 1.5in; height: 0.55in">
<circle id="circle2" r="20" cx="30" cy="30" style="fill: transparent; stroke: black; stroke-width: 2"/>
</svg>
</div>

<div class="TLightG">
<svg id="svg3"style="width: 1.5in; height: 0.55in">
<circle id="circle3" r="20" cx="30" cy="30" style="fill: transparent; stroke: black; stroke-width: 2"/>
</svg>
</div>

<div class="Led1">
<input type="radio" name="Led1" value="0">0
<input type="radio" name="Led1" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="Led1" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="Led1" value="3">3
</div>
```

¿Alguna idea de como hacerlo en HTML? ¿O habría ya que meterse en PHP o JS?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

**EDITO**: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, el problema viene ahora cuando quiero darle un posicionamiento relativo para cada círculo de manera independiente. Ya no puedo usar el **div class="TlightR"** ya que deja de funcionar, alguna idea?

**EDITO2**: Ya lo he conseguido, aunque he tenido que llamar a los círculos con distintas clases para poder meterlos dentro de clases y asignarles posicionamiento relativo dentro del .css

```
<section class="semaforo">  
                            <div class="Cir1">
                      <svg class="semaforo-luz">
                    <circle class="circulo1" cx="20" cy="20" r="20"></circle>
                      </svg>  
                            </div>
                            <div class="Cir2">
                      <svg class="semaforo-luz">
                    <circle class="circulo2" cx="20" cy="20" r="20"></circle>
                      </svg>
                            </div>
                            <div class="Cir3">
                      <svg class="semaforo-luz">
                    <circle class="circulo3" cx="20" cy="20" r="20"></circle>
                      </svg>
                            </div>
                </section>
                <section>
                <div class="Led1Css">
                    <input class="semaforo-sistema" type="radio" name="Led1" value="0">0
                    <input class="semaforo-sistema" type="radio" name="Led1" value="1">1
                    <input class="semaforo-sistema" type="radio" name="Led1" value="2">2
                    <input class="semaforo-sistema" type="radio" name="Led1" value="3">3

</section>

<script>
let eleccion = document.querySelectorAll(".semaforo-sistema")

let circulo1 = document.querySelectorAll(".circulo1")
let circulo2 = document.querySelectorAll(".circulo2")
let circulo3 = document.querySelectorAll(".circulo3")


eleccion.forEach((elemento) => {
    elemento.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (elemento === eleccion[1]) {
        circulo1[0].classList.add("semaforo-rojo")
        circulo2[0].classList.remove("semaforo-amarillo")
        circulo3[0].classList.remove("semaforo-azul")
      } else if(elemento === eleccion[2]) {
        circulo1[0].classList.add("semaforo-rojo")
        circulo2[0].classList.add("semaforo-amarillo")
        circulo3[0].classList.remove("semaforo-azul")
      } else if(elemento === eleccion[3]){
        circulo1[0].classList.add("semaforo-rojo")
        circulo2[0].classList.add("semaforo-amarillo")
        circulo3[0].classList.add("semaforo-azul")  
      } else if(elemento === eleccion[0]){
        circulo1[0].classList.remove("semaforo-rojo")
        circulo2[0].classList.remove("semaforo-amarillo")
        circulo3[0].classList.remove("semaforo-azul")
      }
    })
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hay necesidad de meter al juego a PHP pero si a JS que nos permite acceder a los nodos del DOM.

**Parte 1**

Maneja los colores de fondo que aplicarás por medio de clases que se puedan asignar y remover según sea la necesidad.

```
<style>
  .semaforo-luz {
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 2;
  }
  .semaforo-rojo {
    fill: red;
    stroke-width: 2;
  }
  .semaforo-verde {
    fill: green;
    stroke-width: 2;
  }
</style>
```

**Parte 2**

Reacomoda o considera hacerlo la estructura de tu HTML de este modo:

```
<section>
  <input class="semaforo-sistema" type="radio" name="activador" value="1" />Enciende rojo
  <input class="semaforo-sistema" type="radio" name="activador" value="2" />Enciende verde
  <input class="semaforo-sistema" type="radio" name="activador" value="3" />Enciende amarillo
</section>
<section class="semaforo">
  <svg class="semaforo-luz">
    <circle class="circulo" cx="50" cy="40" r="30"></circle>
  </svg>
  <svg class="semaforo-luz">
    <circle class="circulo" cx="50" cy="40" r="30"></circle>
  </svg>
  <svg class="semaforo-luz">
    <circle class="circulo" cx="50" cy="40" r="30"></circle>
  </svg>
</section>
```

**Parte 3**

Puedes obtener todos los `input` radio por medio de una clase que en común les asignes a todos, lo mismo para los 3 círculos dibujados dándoles una clase en común

```
let eleccion = document.querySelectorAll(".semaforo-sistema")
let circulos = document.querySelectorAll(".circulo")
```

Lo anterior para que puedas iterar los input y reconocer por medio de su posición cual de los 3 esta clikeando el usuario.

Te vales de `classList.add` y de `classList.remove` para agregar o quitar las clases que dan los colores de las luces del semáforo según sea el caso

**EJEMPLO COMPLETO**

> Nota te dejo la lógica para el color amarillo :)

```html
    <style>
      .semaforo-luz {
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 2;
      }
      .semaforo-rojo {
        fill: red;
        stroke-width: 2;
      }
      .semaforo-verde {
        fill: green;
        stroke-width: 2;
      }
    </style>
    <section>
      <input class="semaforo-sistema" type="radio" name="activador" value="1" />Enciende rojo
      <input class="semaforo-sistema" type="radio" name="activador" value="2" />Enciende verde
      <input class="semaforo-sistema" type="radio" name="activador" value="3" />Enciende amarillo
    </section>
    <section class="semaforo">
      <svg class="semaforo-luz">
        <circle class="circulo" cx="50" cy="40" r="30"></circle>
      </svg>
      <svg class="semaforo-luz">
        <circle class="circulo" cx="50" cy="40" r="30"></circle>
      </svg>
      <svg class="semaforo-luz">
        <circle class="circulo" cx="50" cy="40" r="30"></circle>
      </svg>
    </section>
    <script>
      let eleccion = document.querySelectorAll(".semaforo-sistema")
      let circulos = document.querySelectorAll(".circulo")
      
      eleccion.forEach((elemento) => {
        elemento.addEventListener("click", () => {
          if (elemento === eleccion[0]) {
            circulos[0].classList.add("semaforo-rojo")
            circulos[1].classList.remove("semaforo-verde")
          } else if(elemento === eleccion[1]) {
            circulos[1].classList.add("semaforo-verde")
            circulos[0].classList.remove("semaforo-rojo")
          }
        })
      })
    </script>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!! Muy buena explicación y código. Hay alguna manera de ponerle otro identificador para añadirle posicionamiento relativo a cada uno de ellos? Querría posicionarlos en fila y en una posición concreta pero añadir el <div class> para modificarlos en CSS supongo que esa clase se carga a la de svg y deja de funcionar el radio button...

Comment: Solucionado, muchas gracias Aprendiz!